# armature relation off center

Tags: armature, grease-pencil, inverse-kinematics

I have parented a grease pencil drawing to a bone and when I try rotating the bone they don't rotate around the same path. What am I missing? This has worked for me once but then it never worked again so I am at a loss of ideas on what might be wrong.

Starting position
[image: start position]

After rotation
[image: after rotation]

Update: Blender file can be found at

[image]

Please let me know if I need to provide the blender file too.

Comment: I don't know anything about rigging grease pencil, but are you sure the small bone doesn't influence your object?

Comment: I believe not. It is set up for InverseKinematics only. It doesn't have any parent associated.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have attached the blend file. Thank you fot taking a look into this.

Comment: oh ok it's a grease pencil object, I don't know anything about grease pencil and rigging grease pencil so I hope someone will be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens because your Grease Pencil object has transform data (location).

[image]

To fix this: first, in the Stroke tab, unparent the armature from your layer, otherwise the layer will move when you apply the new position.

[image]

Then use Ctrl+A or open the object menu and apply the necessary transforms (in this case, location). After this, your location data should revert to 0 but your drawings will stay in the same position. Then, parent the layers to the armature bones again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I would never guessed that the solution is so simple.